# Pandas dataframe if 3 consecutive numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df`

```
    Price
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    -3
4    3
5    3
```

I wanted to make a column which says `TRUE` if there are 2 positive numbers in a row

So the output is

```
    Price    output
0    3        FALSE
1    3        TRUE
2    3        TRUE
3    -3       FALSE
4    3        FALSE
5    3        TRUE
```

Comment: looks like you want to compare the previous row with current row for positive numbers and not two columns "in a row". Can you please clarify. If it is to compare previous row with current row, then shift(1) will do the trick as suggested by @Sander van der Oord

Answer (score 5):

Use `.shift(1)` to look at the value in the previous row:

```
df['two_positive'] = (df['Price'] >= 0) & (df['Price'].shift(1) >= 0)
```

Result:

```
    Price   two_positive
0   3       False
1   3       True
2   3       True
3   -3      False
4   3       False
5   3       True
```

Comment: Don't believe you need `np.where` here, you can just assign the conditional right off the bat. `df['two_positive'] = (df['Price'] >= 0) & (df['Price'].shift(1) >= 0)`

Comment: completely agree, will adjust my answer, thanks for your comment Cameron, much appreciated! :)